# Remove shortcut progromatically Android 4.0+

Tags: android

I have been removing shortcuts using the intent con.android.launcher.action.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT, but this doesn't seem to work in Android 4.0+ anymore. Has this been deprecated, if so what is the work around?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it was removed, since it was never official API deprecated is not the right word :)
So far could not find a workaround.

If you're trying to prevent duplicates this may work:

```
installer.putExtra("duplicate", false);
```

I'll let you know if I find anything else.